# How to Split content in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I am new to drupal and drupal 7, I saw a video tutorial previous day regarding drupal 6, there they just used this:

```
print $content;
print $title;
```

to display post title and content separately however, in drupal 7 , I copied one of theme page.tpl.php file and there is only  this:

```
 <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

This shows full content inlcuding everything, how do I split them into parts like:

I want to customize my template like this

```
<div id="leftHolder">

                        <h1>Welcome to My site // for header </h1>

                        <p>

                            Some text Portion // 

                        </p>

 </div>
```

This should be same for individual page and front page that shows 2 or 3 posts.

I tried making custom node.tpl.php file too, should I add some special function call to make it able to load content from node.tpl.php file ?

I pasted this code in template to render from page.tpl.php file of my theme

```
function connect_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    $nodetype = $vars['node']->type;
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $nodetype;
}
}
```

Comment: Here's a video for D7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s

Answer (score -1):

In page.tpl.php leave where ever you wants: `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` and then use `node--YOUR_NODE_TYPE.tpl.php` and put content where ever you want. You habe `$node` object print it and see what variables it has.
Make sure that you also have `node.tpl.php` - initial template file in your theme folder.